# Keep current page visible while loading another page with ajax and css transition

Tags: ajax, wordpress, css, ajaxify

I am using ajax to load next page, it works fine. (wordpress with aws ajaxify plugin )

[pastebin of ajax js](http://pastebin.com/R5rPM9NF)

All i want now is to keep current page visible till the next page loads and occupy the viewport.

Here is the link for the demo site m working on http://goo.gl/R8sGB5

So when i click on any link, my ajax plugin does the following

prepare the variables

```
contentSelector = '#' + aws_data['container_id'],
        $content = $(contentSelector),
```

then it add a fade out transition

```
$body.ajaxify();

    // Hook into State Changes
    $(window).bind('statechange',function(){
        // Prepare Variables
        var
        State       = History.getState(),
        url         = State.url,
        relativeUrl = url.replace(rootUrl,'');

        // Set Loading
        $body.addClass('loading');

        // Start Fade Out
        // Animating to opacity to 0 still keeps the element's height intact
        // Which prevents that annoying pop bang issue when loading in new content

        if ( '' != aws_data['transition'] ) {
        $content.animate({opacity:0.6},900);
```

So after this slow fadeout, the plugin request new page with ajax

```
// Ajax Request the Traditional Page
```

And the page loads well. Now here i want to have something like the current page is still visible in background and the new page comes in with a slideLeft Transition.

For which i have my `slideLeft` css class ready .

I am ready to apply the `$content.addClass("slideLeft");`  but when i do this current page disappears first, and then on the black screen next page comes in..

So how can i achieve that, current page remains visible untill next page comes in slide to left most position ?

The very close prototype of how i want it to be is this  https://www.dropbox.com/guide/admin

Thanks

**Edit1**

According to the suggestion by @vinrav , i altered the code but still when the next page loads, the current page disappears

Here is the pastebin of my altered code

http://pastebin.com/gVFjayDK

```
line no 122 to 125( fadeout after ajax request )
line no 140 ( adding transition class)
```

I guess i'm having issues with correct order, looking for help.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order of process for a click.

1. prepare the variables.
2. Let ajax request for the page.
3. Then fade out current page. The fade out time needed to be **large enough to meet the time for fetching the requested page** by ajaxing. It depends on your server speed, client internet speed and other factors.
4. When you get the requested page, start your slide-left transition and if the current page fade out time is large enough you wont get the black screen.

**My recommendation** Wait until you get the requested page via ajax, then only start the fade out of current page. Your close prototype(https://www.dropbox.com/guide/admin) do like that. Dropbox site wait for the response to come from ajax (You can see a bar at top of the page, it tell us to wait... the ajax is on the way... )

**EDIT:**

1. prepare the variables.
2. Let ajax request for the page.
3. Get the requested page.
4. start the fade out.
5. start the slide-left

Comment: thanks for this, i'll try and post result.
Also, is it possible to have the fadeout time as a variable which have the value = ajax request time + some more latency 

or simply a guess of 3 seconds is a good start ?? any idea :-)

Comment: You can get the accurate `ajax request time` only after obtaining the result. which is not what you needed. stick to dropbox plan

Comment: yup!! thats ok.. but somehow i cant get it correct in order as u suggested.
I have updated my question with EDIT1 , IF you can have a luk at pastebin .. and suggest me what i'm doing wrong. that'll be great :-)

Comment: i don't get a chance to be with my computer for a while due to a journey... sorry for that... After going through  your code, i think you are replacing the `<div>` content itself. Actually you need to add a new 'div tag' as sibling and populate it with the ajax result then  slide it to left while your old `div tag` is fading out..